# Python App Engine Queue Tasks

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

I'm trying to run a task on app engine, but i'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR    2012-07-24 18:47:01,030 wsgi.py:189] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 187, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 225, in _LoadHandler
    handler = __import__(path[0])
ImportError: No module named tasks
INFO     2012-07-24 18:47:01,040 dev_appserver.py:2952] "POST /tasks HTTP/1.1" 500 -
WARNING  2012-07-24 18:47:01,045 taskqueue_stub.py:1934] Task task22 failed to execute. This task will retry in 0.100 seconds
```

I'm doing this to add the task:

```
import os
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from controllers.basehandler import BaseHandler
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app


class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler, BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('video_file')
        blob_info = upload_files[0]

        current_user = self.current_user

        if current_user:
            if current_user.video_file_bob:
                old_video = current_user.video_file_bob.key()
                blobstore.delete(old_video)

            current_user.video_file_bob = blob_info.key()
            current_user.put()

            params = {'user':current_user}

            taskqueue.add(url='/tasks')

        self.redirect('/video_upload')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/store_video', UploadHandler)],
                                     debug=True)
```

and this is the code for the task:

```
import re
import urlparse
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from controllers.basehandler import BaseHandler
import gdata.youtube.service
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import logging


class YoutubeUpload(BaseHandler):

    def post(self):
        logging.info('Here')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/tasks', YoutubeUpload)],
                                 debug=True)
```

any ideas on how to solve this?

EDIT

The content of my app.yalm:

```
application: traapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: True

handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: assets/images 
- url: /link_submit
  script: controllers.video_link_submit.app
- url: /video_upload
  script: controllers.video_upload.app
- url: /store_video
  script: controllers.video_upload_handler.app
- url: /tasks
  script: tasks.youtube_upload.app
  login: admin
- url: /.*
  script: controllers.login.app

libraries:
- name: PIL
  version: latest

builtins:
- appstats: on
```

Comment: Can you post the content of your `app.yaml`?

Comment: Updated in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an import error "ImportError: No module named tasks". So I would think that the following would be incorrect.

```
- url: /tasks
  script: tasks.youtube_upload.app
```

What is the path and filename of the second block in your question? The way you have it setup now, you would need to have youtube_upload.app in a /tasks folder that had an **init**.py in it as well.

Comment: you are right, I forgot to put the init.py on the folder. Shame on me, haha. Thank you!